# .SaveChangesAsync() is appending a 1 to my column name making it an invalid column name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm working through Robert Beasley's book on ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages and I'm currently trying to add a row of data to a table using Entity Framework Core. I'm getting an "invalid column name" error for column EmployeeID1. That makes sense because EmployeeID is my Key for the Employee table, I don't have a column EmployeeID1. It seems the error is occurring when .SaveChangesAsync() runs; I can't figure out why the .SaveChangesAsync() method is finding a need to append a 1 to the end of my column name.
I'm looking at:

MaintainInsert.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Chapter21.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Chapter21.Pages
{
public class MaintainInsertModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Chapter21
        .Models.SportsPlayContext SportsPlayContext;
    public MaintainInsertModel(Chapter21
        .Models.SportsPlayContext SPC)
    {
        SportsPlayContext = SPC;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Employee Employee = new Employee();

        Employee.LastName = "Westbrook";
        Employee.FirstName = "Russell";
        Employee.MiddleInitial = "E.";
        Employee.Address = "123 Road Rd";
        Employee.City = "Los Angeles";
        Employee.State = "California";
        Employee.ZipCode = "12312";
        Employee.Phone = "123-123-1234";
        Employee.EmailAddress = "russw@gmail.com";
        Employee.Password = "gimm3";
        Employee.Status = "S";

        SportsPlayContext.Employee.Add(Employee);
        await SportsPlayContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
}
}
```

Here is the scaffolded Employee.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace Chapter21.Models
{
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; internal set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
}
```

An earlier point of confusion was why did it generate both EmployeeId and EmployeeID, but I was able to figure out some problems that caused me - unless this one is also related.

This is the database I'm using: https://github.com/rbeasley-rezine/ASP.NET-Core-Razor-Pages

When I comment out await SportsPlayContext.SaveChangesAsync();
I don't get the error message, but then of course it does not save the changes to the table.

I've tried adding the EmployeeID property to the new Employee object, which should be unnecessary because it's the key, and I've tried countless other things which I don't remember now.

I'll be happy to provide more info if I've not provided enough context.

Comment: I would remove the public int EmployeeId { get; set; } as this is not necessary and could be causing the other problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Having both an `EmployeeId` and an `EmployeeID` property is probably the cause. It would confuse anybody using that class and if it's trying to name columns avoiding collisions in a *case insensitive* manner, the obvious choice is to append a number until it's unique.

Comment: I think that EmployeeId maybe would be the one to keep actually because of this line in my SportsPlayContext.cs class
     entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("EmployeeID");
However, removing one or the other creates other problems which boils down to another error when I account for those which is SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: That's all to say that I think you're right, at least to some extent. I'll have to check my other pages to make sure I didn't cause more errors but, even before that, it's still not functioning correctly.